# Can't boot without acpi=off

Tags: linux, boot, grub

First: this might gonna get a long one, but I‘m desperately looking for help!
Second: I‘m a total newb on Linux, so I have really limited Linux know-how.

Specs:

- Asus ROG Strix G15DS-R7700X088W
- AMD Ryzen 7 7700X
- NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3070
- 2x 1TB SSDs; 1x M2 NVME with W11 running, 1x SATA

Goal:
Running Dual Boot with W11 on the first M2 SSD (already running fine) and Linux on the second SATA SSD

Distros I tried:

- Nobara 39
- Fedora 39
- Fedora 38
- Fedora Silverblue
- Ubuntu 22.04
- Pop!_OS
- Linux Mint
- Arch Linux
- GarudaOS
- GarudaOS Dr460nized

Problem I run into:
I can‘t boot even from the LiveUSB without the „acpi=off“ option. If I do, I get just a black Screen (with Backlight still on) or, if I get into the Grub options first, there‘s only „booting command list“ visible but nothing else happens (even with „quiet“ disabled, no info on the Screen at all).
One thing I noticed, since my Keyboard, Mouse and Mousemat (Razerfly) have lighting, when I try to boot without the acpi=off, they go dark. And stay dark. With acpi=off the keyboard alone goes dark but then lights up again after 2-3 seconds.
If I run it with acpi=off, I can boot and install, but I then have to boot every time with acpi=off. This leads to the graphics driver not being recognized by the OS and running always in 1024x768 „software rendering“ resolution (even with proper drivers installed and enabled and nouveau on blacklist). So just let „acpi=off“ enabled isn‘t an option.
Also, when trying to boot without acpi=off I see that straight after hitting enter, my USBs seem to go off (by seeing that the RGB on Keyboard, Mouse and Mousepad go off completely).

I already reached out to several communities over reddit/discord/kbin/lemmy (linuxquestions, linux4noobs, asus-linux, linux, nobara, popos, and maybe even several more) but didn't find any solution yet.

- BIOS/UEFI is up to date, no newer version available.
- Secure Boot is off (=set to "Custom OS")
- Fast Boot is off

What I tried (by googling myself and/or by getting answer's from the other comms):
Boot with different options:

- acpi=strict / acpi=force / acpi=ht / noacpi / acpi=noirq / acpi=irqfixup
- noapic / nolapic
- pci=nommsconf
- pci=biosirq
- pci=noacpi
- iommu=soft / iommu=off
- nomodeset / nvidia-drm.modeset=0 / nvidia-drm.modeset=1 / nouveau.blacklist=1
- ibt=off

burn the ISOs with different software:

- Rufus
- Ventoy
- Fedora Media Writer

Other:

- swap USB Slots / Sticks
- went through my UEFI Settings several times, trying to enable/disable tons different options
- disable onboard graphics with nvidia gpu enabled and the other way round (even tried by removing the nvidia card completely)
- tried to install older versions of the distro's with older kernels
- googled around for days already without any luck...

And mybe even more options with no luck until now, nothing has changed. I see with "insmode progress" in grub, that kernel and initrd are loading but after that nothing happens. No logs at all, just a black screen with backlight on or just one line stating "booting a command line" when adjusted some grub options beforehand.

I reached out to ASUS as well, but got no respone from them up until now. I'm now in a state, where I think about swapping my MoBo, but got the suggestion, to try asking on here, so that I have all options covered.
So, does someone knows how I can tackle that? I can provide more info, if needed, just do tell what's missing.

Thank you for having read this wall of text, just wanted to be as detailed as possible...